# JQuery set selected option using value not working

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

Here's my jQuery code

```
$("#addHospitalState").val("FL");
```

Value for state dropdown is not getting set.

HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-left" for="addHospitalState">State:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
<select name="addHospitalState" id="addHospitalState" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
</div>
```

Options are populated using ajax post call

Comment: We can't help you if we don't even know how does your select look like .. Add your HTML code at least

Comment: where are the options?????

Comment: where are the options???

Comment: @PranavCBalan is right : Where are the options ? You can't select an option if it doesn't even exist ..

Comment: Options are populated using ajax post call

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the option first, then setting the value:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#addHospitalState').append('<option>FL</option>').val('FL');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-left" for="addHospitalState">State:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
    <select name="addHospitalState" id="addHospitalState" class="form-control">
      <option>Select</option>  
    </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Options are getting populated using ajax call.

heres my code

function setModalValues(affiliation_id,rowId) {
 var tableId = '#dataTable';
 populateStates();
 var state = $(tableId).dataTable().fnGetData(rowId).state;
 $("#addHospitalState").val(state);
 populateCities();
 var city = $(tableId).dataTable().fnGetData(rowId).city;
 $('#addHospitalCity').val(city);
 populateNames();
 var name = $(tableId).dataTable().fnGetData(rowId).hospitalName;
 $('#addHospitalState').val(name);
}

Comment: sounds like your code is running before the options are populated

Comment: I am setting it once the optios are populated